# Receive extra from a notification action button

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

My app is pushing a notification at a specific date in the future.
In the notification you shall have two options:

1. Click the notification body --> open the app normally
2. Click the action button in the notification --> open the app and perform an action

In order to do so, I want to add an extra to the intent which can be read when starting the app. Therefore I set up the notification receiver as following:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent contentIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, App.REMINDERS_ID, contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

    Intent extendIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    extendIntent.putExtra(App.BUNDLE_ACTION, App.ACTION_EXTEND_WEAR);
    PendingIntent extendPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, App.REMINDERS_ID, extendIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_REMINDERS_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_calendar_today_24)
            .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("title"))
            .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("text"))
            .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
            .addAction(0,intent.getStringExtra("action_extend"), extendPendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    // .addAction(0,intent.getStringExtra("action_stop"), contentIntent)


    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 1);
    notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
}
```

No, when the app starts, I want to check if the intent has an extra (BUNDLE_ACTION) or not.

```
Bundle bundle = this.getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey(App.BUNDLE_ACTION)) {
        // Perform the action on app start
        Log.e(App.TAG, "Action received from notification! Action = " + bundle.getInt(App.BUNDLE_ACTION));
    } else {
        Log.e(App.TAG, "No action received from notification.");
    }
```

The extra is received, the Log entry is shown accordingly.
But, the extra is received either I press the notification body or the notification action button.

Can anybody advise me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to create two different `PendingIntent`s, but your code actually only creates one `PendingIntent.` The first call creates a new `PendingIntent`:

```
Intent contentIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, App.REMINDERS_ID, contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
```

The second call **does not create** a new `PendingIntent`. Instead, because the contents of `contentIntent` **match** the contents of `extendIntent`, the call to `PendingIntent.getActivity()` actually returns the `PendingIntent` previously created in the first call:

```
Intent extendIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
extendIntent.putExtra(App.BUNDLE_ACTION, App.ACTION_EXTEND_WEAR);
PendingIntent extendPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, App.REMINDERS_ID, extendIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
```

This is because when comparing the two `Intent`s, the "extras" in the `Intent`s are ignored.

To fix this you need to make sure that the `PendingIntent`s are unique. There are many ways to do this, here are a few:

- Add an ACTION to each `Intent` and make sure that they are different
- Use different `requestCode` in each call to `PendingIntent.getActivity()` (instead of using `App.REMINDERS_ID` for both

Comment: Sir, you are my hero! Thanks! using different request codes did the job.